# How to optimize github action with mounted volume for yarn application

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops, hadoop-yarn

We use k8s github-runner for multiples yarn applications.

Using the caching, the runner needs to download a tarball and extract which is quite long to process.

We want to accelerate the caching using network volumes.

For example, we did a mounted network volume for `/var/lib/docker` to accelerate our docker build steps.

How is this possible?

1. Does yarn look for cached module locally first when running `yarn` ?
2. We use `.nvm` to handle multiple yarn version ?